# How to render an image from int array of pixel values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a client side program that currently parses .dcm files and extracts the image pixels into an array of pixel values ranging from 0-255.

Is there a way to render this pixel array in react?

Thanks,

Comment: this may help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

Comment: I do have to ask, is there a particular reason you want to do this on the client side?

Comment: @EyalPerry, it's because the user has to be able to highlight specific parts of the image, I.E, set all values between 200-220 to 0, and it would be alot smoother doing this client side.

Answer (score 1):

Try This
[dom-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-to-image)

The condition is that the input array must be a raw pixel data as a Uint8Array with every 4 array elements representing the RGBA data of a pixel